# Excel macro date parser cannot handle single-digit days

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, macros, date

From previous questions on this and other sites I was given a function that can parse for and find dates in text strings or cells. Here's the function:

```
Function GetDate(strInput As String) As Date

    Dim DateFormat() As String
    Dim intDateLength As Integer
    Dim intMaxFormat As Integer
    Dim intFrmtCtr As Integer
    Dim intPosition As Integer

    intMaxFormat = 6
    ReDim DateFormat(1 To intMaxFormat)

    DateFormat(1) = "*##[-/]##[/-]####*"
    DateFormat(2) = "*#[-/]##[-/]####*"
    DateFormat(3) = "*##[-/]#[-/]####*"
    DateFormat(4) = "*##[-/]##[-/]##*"
    DateFormat(5) = "*#[-/]##[-/]##*"
    DateFormat(6) = "*#[-/]#[-/]##*"

    GetDate = Now

    For intFrmtCtr = 1 To intMaxFormat
        If strInput Like DateFormat(intFrmtCtr) Then
            intDateLength = Len(DateFormat(intFrmtCtr)) - 8
            strInput = Replace(strInput, " ", "")

            For intPosition = 1 To Len(strInput)
                If Mid(strInput, intPosition, intDateLength) Like DateFormat(intFrmtCtr) Then
                    GetDate = DateValue(Mid(strInput, intPosition, intDateLength))
                    Exit Function
                End If
            Next intPosition
        End If
    Next intFrmtCtr

End Function
```

This is then called by referencing a cell address:

```
'Gets date from cell A2
    Range("A2").Select
    dateWork = GetDate(Selection)
```

I can then format the output using `Format(dateWork, "mmddyy")` or similar.

In the case above, given a cell contents of `8/31/2011` the string `08312011` is returned.

Beginning with cell content dates with a single digit day (ie, early in the month), though, the function began returning the first two digits of the year instead of the second two digits. All of a sudden, dates started looking like they were in 2020, not 2011.

I've been able to test this using otherwise identical input data sheets where dates up to and including `8/31/2011` were returned correctly and dates beginning with `9/1/2011` and continuing all return "20" as the year.

Where is this function breaking down?

UPDATE clarification for questions:

I use this function in several macros acting upon data exported from a report-generating tool (Business Objects). It is possible to manually edit the date in the input files, but that rather defeats the purpose of the macros and so should not be considered an option.

The GetDate() function can be called upon to find dates in any string. The strings can be just the date in any of various formats, or they can be combinations of text and date such as "Totals as of 9/13/1977".

I would appreciate your simplification or edits to the function so long as it retains the abilities laid out above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Mid(strInput, intPosition, intDateLength)` isn't working for you. For 9/1/2011, you're matching  `DateFormat(6) = "*#[-/]#[-/]##*"`. So `Mid(strInput, intPosition, intDateLength) = Mid("9/1/2011", 1, 6)` and returns "9/1/20" rather than "9/1/2011".

based on your example above, I think you need to add 2 more patterns so that you cover all combinations of 1 and 2 digit months/days & 2 and 4 digit years. Order is important because you want to match the 4 digit years first (noting that the reason you have a problem is that *#/#/##* matches 9/1/2011 when in fact you only want it to match 9/1/11. So the code change is something like the below. I haven't exhaustively tested it with all date formats, but it seems OK.

```
intMaxFormat = 8
ReDim DateFormat(1 To intMaxFormat)

DateFormat(1) = "*##[-/]##[/-]####*"
DateFormat(2) = "*#[-/]##[-/]####*"
DateFormat(3) = "*##[-/]#[-/]####*"
DateFormat(4) = "*#[-/]#[-/]####*"
DateFormat(5) = "*##[-/]##[-/]##*"
DateFormat(6) = "*##[-/]#[-/]##*"
DateFormat(7) = "*#[-/]##[-/]##*"
DateFormat(8) = "*#[-/]#[-/]##*"
```

Comment: Is that due to the single-digit day?

Comment: Yes. DateFormat(6) is effectively *m/d/yy*, which is the only one that 9/1/2011 matches. The other formats all require a 2 digit day or month. So if you put in 09/01/2011, it would work fine

Comment: If you can tell me what you're trying to achieve, I can simplify the function for you. I think there's some redundant bits in it, especially if all your dates are the same format.

Comment: I've added clarification regarding what sort of strings GetDate() works upon and it's requirements per my usage.

Comment: Looking at the DateFormats you've added, should numbers 6 and 7 be reversed? Numbers 2 and 3 go in what appear to be the opposite order from 6 and 7. Which is correct (or should they be in the order you've given them)?

Comment: I haven't had time to try this out myself in code. Only on paper. The key is to make sure that each date matches the longest, and therefore most specific, pattern possible. The biggest issue is the *## and ##*'s on the ends though as they are wildcards and therefore catching the 2 and 4 digit years. I think it works either way around, but you're right, for consistency I think you should reverse   6&7 or 2&3.

Comment: Ok. I've applied the fix and will try and test some files to see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

For accepting both 2 and 4 digits year, (where 2 digits is less than 1000)
I used one line to check all about date, that's:

```
If IsDate(date) And Len(Trim(Year(date))) = 2 Or Len(Trim(Year(date))) = 4 Then
GoTo Action 'Continue with the macro
Else: "Your Message"
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I've written a shorter macro that should do what you want.  It splits the string up into an array by the space character.  The macro then runs through the array looking for the date.  If there are extra characters attached to the date it will fail.  However, if the date is its "own word" separated by spaced on both ends it works perfectly.  Depending on your needs it may need to be modified a little bit.

```
Function GetDate(strInput As String) As Date

 Dim strDate() As String, i As Long

  strDate = Split(strInput, " ")

 For i = 0 To UBound(strDate) - 1
    If Right(strDate(i), 1) = "." Then strDate(i) = Left(strDate(i), Len(strDate(i)) - 1)
    If IsDate(strDate(i)) Then
       GetDate = strDate(i)
       Exit For
    End If
 Next i

End Function
```

Comment: It looks like that handles dates followed by periods, right? But other characters such as commas and other punctuation may cause problems?

Comment: Yup.  In my simple test I had a period.  You could test each string for a number at the end and delete if it is not.  Without knowing his exact requirements it is impossible to write code effectively.